# Why do I get this error inserting a character into a MATLAB matrix?

Tags: matlab, matrix, character

I am constructing a 16x16 matrix, consisting of just letters in MATLAB. I tried for example:

```
for i=1:2:3
    C(i,2)=char('B');    
end
```

to place the letter `'B'` in its corresponding place in the matrix. However this gives a value of `66` in the matrix instead of just the letter `'B'`. What is going wrong?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is most likely that you already have a variable called `C` that contains *numeric* data in it. When you try to place a character into a numeric matrix, the character gets converted to its ASCII value. If you clear the variable `C` before running your above code, you should get a character matrix for `C`:

```
>> clear C
>> for i=1:2:3, C(i,2) = 'B'; end
>> C

C =

 B

 B
```

Note in this case that `C` is a 3-by-2 array with null characters (ASCII code `0`) in the first column and second row of the second column. If you want to initialize `C` to be a 16-by-16 character array of null characters, you can replace the [CLEAR](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/clear.html) statement in the above code with:

```
C = char(zeros(16));
```

And then run your loop to fill in your values. Also note that `char('B')` is redundant, since `'B'` is already of type character.

Answer (score 0):

If I do

```
for i=1:3
    C(i)=char('A');
end
```

I get `C=AAA`, as you'd expect. I suspect the reason why you're getting the decimal value of the char is because you might have preallocated `C` as `C=zeros(16)`. MATLAB initialized the array as `numeric` type and accordingly, when you replaced an element with a `char`, it promptly converted it to its numeric value.

A better approach would be to use `cells` and then convert it to a matrix.

```
C=cell(4,4);%# create an empty 4x4 cell
for i=1:16
    C{i}=char('A');
end

C=


    'A'    'A'    'A'    'A'
    'A'    'A'    'A'    'A'
    'A'    'A'    'A'    'A'
    'A'    'A'    'A'    'A'
```

Now use `cell2mat` to convert it to a matrix:

```
Cmatrix=cell2mat(C)

Cmatrix=

    AAAA
    AAAA
    AAAA
    AAAA
```

Normally, I wouldn't use loops, but I don't know your exact requirements, so I've shown an example as per your question.

Answer (score 0):

Matlab stores the letter 'B' as integer ASCII code. Ini fact, char means int8.